# server not getting image datas while posting from iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, http

I am posting multiple images to server url,But i am facing one issue.
After posting the image datas,The serever get only the image data i send first.The remaining datas are null.But at the time of posting i can print the datas (NSLog)

Please help me to understand the problem
Giving my code here

**UploadImageViewController.m**

```
-(IBAction)upPic:(id)sender{
UploadImage *up_image = [[UploadFood alloc] init];

  [up_image sendServerRequests:[NSDictionary  dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"pic1.jpg",@"filename",@"pic2.jpg",@"filename2", nil]  file:sharedClass.picData file1:sharedClass.picData2];


   }
```

**UploadImage.m**

```
-(void)sendServerRequests:(NSDictionary *)bits file:(NSData *)file file1:(NSData *)file1 file2:(NSData *)file2 {
 NSLog(@"file  %@",file );


 [postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:file]];

 [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data;  name=\"image2\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", [bits objectForKey:@"filename2"]]  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [postbody appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

  NSLog(@"file1 %@",file1);


  [postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:file1]];

  [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image3\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", [bits objectForKey:@"filename3"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [postbody appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

  NSLog(@"file2 %@",file2);  // i am able to print data here

  [postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:file2]];



  [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


   [request setHTTPBody:postbody];


  conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (conn) {
    webData = [NSMutableData data];
   }


  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Nithin MK AS per your code you did all things perfectly ok.

in the current situation, only the first file is uploading on the server. I think if you are not uploading the first file and uploading the second file it would be uploaded.

So I suggest that you can use the array for this. if your web service using php/.net then you can use the array for the file name.

so try with use

> name=\"image2[]\";
>
> name=\"image3[]\";

and also please check your web service with this.

Thanks.